# Postgres batch operation

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying for batch operation on Postgres using Go. I am getting `"insufficient data left in a message (SQLSTATE 08P01)"`. I am sure this message could occur because of the null values. If I try with valid not null-values then also it ends with the same error.

Sample code:

```golang
func updateBatch(rCtx context.Context, s core.Datastore, records []DetailedAlbum) (err error) {
    L := logger.GetLogger(rCtx)

    masterPool := s.MustPool()
    txMaster, _ := masterPool.Begin()
    defer func() {
        if err = txMaster.Rollback(); err != nil {
            if err == pgx.ErrTxClosed {
                return
            }
            L.WithError(err).Error("failed to rollback transaction")
            return
        }
    }()

    b := txMaster.BeginBatch()
    //var args []interface{}
    for _, u := range records {
        now := time.Now()
        details := &pgtype.JSONB{}
        err = details.Set(u.fullDetail)
        if err != nil {
            L.WithError(err).Error("failed to parse interface{}")
            return err
        }

        x := store.AlbumSpotifySchema{SpotifyID: u.ID, DetailAlbum: details}
        //args = []interface{}{x.SpotifyID, &x.DetailAlbum}
        args := []interface{}{details, u.ID}
        print(x.SpotifyID, " ------ ", now.String(), "\n")
        b.Queue("update spotify_albums set detail_album = $1 where album_id = $2", args, nil, nil)
    }
    opt := pgx.TxOptions{}
    err = b.Send(rCtx, &opt)
    if err != nil {
        // It's very important to close the batch operation on error
        if e := b.Close(); e != nil {
            L.WithError(e).Error("failed to close batch")
            return e
        }
        L.WithError(err).Error("failed to send batch")
        return err
    }

    if err = b.Close(); err != nil {
        L.WithError(err).Error("failed to close batch")
        return err
    }
    if err = txMaster.Commit(); err != nil {
        L.WithError(err).Error("failed to commit transaction")
        return err
    }

    cmd, err := b.ExecResults()
    if err != nil {
        L.WithError(err).Error("failed to exec results")
        return err
    }
    L.Warnf("rows affected: %d", cmd.RowsAffected())

    return nil
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `Queue("...", args, nil, nil)`? What's the point of those `nil`s? Shouldn't the number of arguments match that of the parameter references in the query? e.g. if the query has `$1` and `$2` the number of arguments should also be 2, yet you pass in 3 arguments `args, nil, nil`, why? What happens if you do `Queue("...", args...)`? Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Refer this document https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/v3/batch.go

Comment: I see, I was looking at [v4](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/master/batch.go#L22)... For v3 if you do something like [this](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/v3/batch_test.go#L25-L49) do you still get the same error? If you can you might wanna switch to v4 though.

Comment: It solved. I was missing `[]pgtype.OID{pgtype.JSONBOID, pgtype.VarcharOID}`. I was passing nil.